# rename wordpress theme name to client name

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

is it **legal** to change a wordpress theme name (premium theme or not) to something else (for example a client's name) so people won't know the theme a wordpress site is using?

Thanks

Comment: depends on the terms by which you obtained the theme and the license it is released under. Mostly yea you are ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you have modified it directly and not using child theme, yo can definitely give it a name .But the problem is you will not get support from the developers and you can not update it, better to use a child theme and if you know the child theme concept It is far better option as you are making a theme with a name you want and you are still able to use new updates and support from the theme developer team.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but if I name my child theme anything, how would wordpress know what the parent theme of my child theme is?

Comment: You have to put `Template:     your master theme name` .No true method of hiding theme name , if you want to update .

Answer (score 0):

It's allowed, but you would forfeit any support offered by the theme author. It also could produce errors depending on the theme. To change just go into the theme folder and alter the style.css

[themeforest ref](http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/rename-theme-is-that-ok/111174) 
[themeforest ref 2](http://themeforest.net/licenses/faq#modify-a)

Answer (score 0):

You can creat a child theme and give whatever your wish then access functionality from parent theme.